# Variables in an image_tag within rails will not output a digest value in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a tag which essentially looks like this:

`<%= image_tag("people/#{person.department}/#{person.name}.jpg") %>`

In production, the output is `<img src="/assets/people/math/bob.jpg">`

However, as with other image_tags, I would expect (and desire) the output to include the digest of the precompiled asset: `<img src="/assets/people/math/bob-23u8518sd83yr822243dj0f.jpg">`

Is it not possible for image_tags which are used with a variable to include their digest in production? As a note other assets, such as my CSS, JS and other images which do not use variables are successfully using their digest values, so this shouldn't be a configuration issue.

Edit
I've done some additional testing, this appears to affect my Heroku deployment specifically.

Comment: Just for thought what difference would it make anyway

Comment: Rails providing the digest in the URL allows me to set long cache expires values in CloudFront (or, for that matter, anywhere you're setting your cache headers on static assets). With the digest, whenever that image is updated, the client's browser will request the new image as the digest value has changed, and to the browser, it's an entirely new asset which it doesn't already have cached. Without this, I cannot make the assumption that returning users would be seeing any updated images.

Comment: Weird for me it take the digest

Answer (score 1):

You can use Sprockets' `find_asset` method, passing in a logical path to your asset to get a `Sprockets::BundledAsset` instance. For example

```
> Rails.application.assets.find_asset("people/#{person.department}/#{person.name}.jpg")
=> #<Sprockets::BundledAsset:0x3fe1142a4f10 pathname="/Users/timdorr/Projects/MyApp/app/assets/people/math/bob.jpg", mtime=2013-09-13 01:33:57 -0500, digest="23u8518sd83yr822243dj0f">
```

You can call `digest_path` on this object to get it's `MD5` sum appended to the asset.

```
> Rails.application.assets.find_asset("people/#{person.department}/#{person.name}.jpg").digest_path
=> "people/math/bob-23u8518sd83yr822243dj0f.jpg"
```

With this knowledge you can easily create a helper to return the `digest_path` for any asset in your application, and call this helper from within your view templates.